# Holidays gem: How to Add a region with its holidays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, holidays-gem

I've already made this YAML file, but i don't know what to do nect.

> ```
> months:
>   1: 
>   - name: Ra's Essana
>     regions: ["islam"]
>     mday: 1
>   
>
>   
> tests: |
>
>     { Date.civil(1531,1,1) => 'Ra's Essana',
>      }.each do |date, name|
>        assert_equal name, (Holidays.on(date, :no, :informal)[0] || {})[:name]
>      end
> ```

Any Ideas? It's just a short example, but I have no Idea how to add it...

Answer (score 1):

The instructions on how to contribute to(extend) the `holidays` gem are on its [github page](https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays)

> How to contribute
>
> To make changes to any of the definitions, edit the YAML files only.
>
> Tests are also added at the end of the YAML files. Please add tests,
>   it makes the pull requests go around.
>
> After you're satisfied with the YAML file, edit the `index.yaml` file,
>   `run rake generate`, which will generate the Ruby files that make up the
>   actual code as well as the tests. Then run rake test.
>
> It is also very appreciated if documentation is attached to the pull
>   request. A simple Wikipedia or government link referencing the change
>   would be perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I allready tried this. It won't work, because everytime I try {rake generate}, I get C:\Users\patolla>rake generate
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: @user3383458 you need to be in the holidays gem folder, you probably want to clone the project and before following the instructions